# Netty, Serve connected clients with data from mongo db

Tags: mongodb, netty

trying hardly to find a solution / answer for my problem.

I am having a backend server that is producing data (information) which is being stored into a mongo db database.

An additional server (running netty) should serve the connected clients (10k clients).

Where should i place the database query, since not all clients are interested in the same information?

I came up with following ideas:

- # 1 Having a separate thread in the application which is hosting the netty server, performing the database query and looping over all connected clients and sending (channel.writeAndFlush(info)) the information (if the client is interested in it).

The first problem i see is that i am having only one thread which should serve all clients.
Second, i am retrieving much information out of the database and fiter it in the application even if the interested client is not connected. I think that this could lead to performance issues.

- # 2 Perform a much more detailed query within the channel thread (maybe idlestatehandler?)
  and send all received data back to the client

I am interested to know which concept would be better in scalability and performance.

I am sure this is a common use case. But i was not able to find a solution.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Your idea sounds OK to me. Maybe you could maintain some data structure instead of the simple list of channels so you don't always have to loop over the channel list.  What other problems do you see with your idea?

Comment: @trustin, I thought instead of having one big thread querying the database i could make use of the channel thread and query only for the needed data. But where to place that code?

Comment: @user3211074 Can you tell how did you manage to use netty with mongoDB? Sorry for trivial question, I'm newbie in netty? And also could please guide me to better understand netty, any book or reference? Thanks beforehand!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you want to use the channel thread because with 10K clients, and assuming 4 CPUs, by default you'll have 1250 clients per thread and you won't be able to write data to all clients bound to a given thread while you're querying mongo-db.

I'd use a separate thread pool. For each channel just queue a task to retrieve the data for that channel. When the query returns you can post a user event to the channel to perform the write in the I/O thread (perhaps post 'info' as one of the user event fields). This way you can tune the size of the thread pool taking into account things like server capacity and maximum number of connections to mongo-db.

If the channels are persistent, and you're periodically polling for data while the channel is connected, the same model works. Just use a ScheduledExecutorService instead of a normal executor and schedule the task to repeat.

You will have to deal with the channel closing while the query is running. If this happens relatively infrequently I'd be tempted to catch the exception Netty throws when you try to queue the user event in your executor, rather than try to check if the channel is open before posting the event.

Comment: Thank you, the concept seems to work. What is the name for this design pattern?

Comment: I'm not sure if there's a specific pattern name. It shares elements of SEDA where an "event" is handed off to the next thread pool for handling but it's not quite the same.